# linux: perf cannot inject var/line probes: Mismatching build id

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, perf

I've installed most recent debuginfo on a recent fedora for **perfing** especially for kernel vars.

Am at the end of my tether. I must me doing something stupidly wrong, since checking around I saw no further complaints for most recent stable debug kernel out.

```
[root@fedora24 ~]# uname -r
4.9.7-101.fc24.x86_64+debug
```

This is what am mainly up to, injecting VAR probes. Looks a little convoluted, but have to point to vmlinux since of some perf path resolution bug.

```
[root@fedora24 ~]# perf probe -k /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/modules/4.9.7-101.fc24.x86_64/vmlinux --add 'tc_modify_qdisc:20 clid'
Failed to find the path for kernel: Mismatching build id
  Error: Failed to add events.
```

It's true:

```
[root@fedora24 ~]# perf buildid-list 
d9e7ab1e71c82e23838ff6ef39adc891854b343e [kernel.kallsyms]
b33e1cebcbc9a01bf21fd788196dd38dac8cbef1 [vdso]
```

and for running kernel:

```
[root@fedora24 ~]# perf buildid-list -k
da80db1851d800a19338964a22f0d2d58ab45ec3
```

The ids do differ. But that's no surprise to me, and I've installed all that from main upstream fedora repo. Are they really offering differing code for
debuginfo pkgs and their debug-kernel. That'd be odd!

I've tried purging pkgs and ignoring Build-Ids without success.

Really strange, and every input appreciated!

BR

Comment: Try to install debuginfo from fedora which matches your exact kernel version or reinstall some other (older) pair of kernel and debuginfo. Your kernel may be not the recent or you installed newer debuginfo. Or you can try to rebuild kernel by yourself with generating of debuginfo.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Upgraded to latest. Was working then, but their debuginfo is does not include all symbols. :) Will end up building myself anyways, what counters the idea of prebuilt debuginfos somehow. Cheers.